# Get Instance Count of Azure Web App with C#

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been looking around and I can't find a concise example around getting this metric.  I've installed `WindowsAzure.Management.Compute` and now I don't know where to begin.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look at Azure Resource Explorer: https://resources.azure.com. You could find the instances request URL as following:

[image]

For the Authorization header please have a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx). We can use C# HttpRequest to write the code. Here is the result I tested in fildder.

**the endpoint:**

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/jatestgroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/testcore1/instances?api-version=2015-08-01

**Result:**

[image]

We can calculate the instance number from the response json. In addition, it will need a long time in this rest API to show all instances when scale the instance in azure portal.

**[Update]**

According with my comment, I tested with the article:http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/#.V9tLKyh95hF

The following is my result:

[image]

Please download the library at [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/). Refer to [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/windows-azure-management-certificates/) for more information about Windows Azure Management Certificates.

Here is the code snipped:

```html
     var cert = new X509Certificate2();

     cert.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(""));

     var _client = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.WebSiteManagementClient(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CertificateCloudCredentials("****", cert));

     var ids=  await  _client.WebSites.GetInstanceIdsAsync("EastAsiawebspace", "testcore1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the instance count from within one instance of the Web App. But you can get it from the portal, or from the Azure ARM API (it's the `numberOfWorkers` property on the Web Hosting Plan object).

Also, note that `WindowsAzure.Management.Compute` does not apply to Azure Web App.

Comment: I'm attempting to feed some metrics into my app via C# - one of these is the current instance count.  Can I use the Azure ARM Api with C#?  If so, would you mind providing an example of how to get this information?